# Listener for keydown is triggered multiple times instead of once

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
undoButton.onclick = undoFunction;
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.code === "KeyZ") {
    e.preventDefault();
    undoFunction();
  }
});

function undoFunction() {
  console.log("undo function...");
}
```

When I click the button, as excepted, the function code runs once, and so does the console.log, but when I use the key stroke, the function is running a multiple times, up to hundreds of so-called loops at some scenarios. Any suggestion why? I tried to used `e.repeat = false` but had no luck. Thanks!

Comment: What is the context for the code you posted? It's important to understand that `.addEventListener()` does just that: it **adds** an event listener, without removing any previously-added event listeners. If you do that over and over again, **all** of the added event listeners will run on every "keydown" event.

Comment: What you are looking for is debouncing: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Comment: @mashuptwice Not needed here at all

Comment: The keydown event triggers multiple times while you're holding down the button because your keyboard sends the key multiple times. Just like holding a keyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy here in the text field.

Comment: Try using keyup or keypressed instead

Answer (score 1):

Use keyup instead. The keydown event triggers as long a key is hold down. keyup only triggers when a key is released.

```js
var undoButton = document.getElementById('undoButton');
undoButton.onclick = undoFunction;
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.code === "KeyZ") {
    e.preventDefault();
    undoFunction();
  }
});

function undoFunction() {
  console.log("undo function...");
}
```

```html
<input id="undoButton" type="button" value="Undo" />
```